# Javascript with SJCL lib, decrypt AES in GCM mode

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I try to decrypt an cipher with AES in GCM mode with the SJCL library in Javascript (from within CasperJS).
When I execute the code below the error I receive is:

error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.encrypt([0,
0,0,0])')

The code:

```
var masterkey = '39537496606860671661230109146651832357';
var cipher = 'Sa2Rk3bbdiaI7mO/';
var iv = '59804781381539321505720964105';
var authdata = '199590863504973848417387014842606357793';

var decff = sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt(masterkey, cipher, iv, authdata);
console.log (decff);
```

As you can see, I am basically just calling the decrypt function as the SJCL docs told me to.

The encryption was done in python with this code: https://github.com/bozhu/AES-GCM-Python Wich I found is this thread: [AES in GCM mode in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958088/aes-in-gcm-mode-in-python)

Is there anything special I have to consider when encrypting in one language and decrypting in another? Im afraid so...
Can I check somehow if the encryption information are valid AES/GCM?
Im not really sure how to proceed here since Im no JS or Python or encryption expert.

For background information:
I try to achieve a more or less secure encryption in pure python (so I can run it on Google App Engine) and the fitting decryption in pure JS.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You shouldn't directly use `sjcl.mode.gcm`, but rather `sjcl.decrypt` from [convenience.js](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/src/core_convenience.js.html). You also have to keep in mind that authdata is not the same as the (auth) tag. Make sure you know which is which. Note, the first argument to `sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt` is a prf, not the key

Comment: thx for your help. im just wondering: how am i supposed to know that?

Comment: If the documentation doesn't give you what you want to know, you have to look into the source code as I did. It is possible that sjcl.decrypt doesn't expose all options that you need to make it work, so you would need to use `sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt`. When you find an answer, add an answer yourself.

Comment: How can this be? You asked about GCM mode which CryptoJS doesn't support.

Comment: It uses OFB mode. As I wrote, in general I just need to encrypt, doesnt need to be AES/GCM.

Comment: we are talking about this btw: https://gist.github.com/andres-erbsen/1307675.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly decrypt try converting your encrypted string, cypher, IV and auth data to bitArray.

```
 const data = sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt(cipherArray, encryptedBitArray, iv, authArray, 128);
```

Here 128 is size you can use 256 as well.

Also try to append your IV with the encypted string.

```
 const bitArray = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(content);
  const bitArrayCopy = bitArray.slice(0);
  const ivdec = bitArrayCopy.slice(0, 4);
  const encryptedBitArray = bitArray.slice(4);
  var key = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits("2d73c1dd2f6a3c981afc7c0d49d7b58f");
  let cipher = new sjcl.cipher.aes(key);
```